# Convert an eigenvalue equation to ODE/s

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, differential-operators, eigenfunctions

For example define: $K=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ (non-discrete spectrum), so:

$$Kf(x)=-i\frac{df}{dx}=kf(x)$$

Define $g(x,k)=kf(x)$, so:

$$\frac{-i}{k}\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}}=g(x,k)$$
$$\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}}f(x)=g(x,k)$$
Which implies (Not sure this helps):
$$Kf(x)=\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}}g(x,k)$$

My question is: How/Can I transform the above (or something else related, maybe using functionals of $f$) to ODE/s, and then solve for the eigenfunctions without use of the eigenvalues?

Comment: $-i \dfrac{df}{dx} = k f(x)$ is already an ODE, and easy to solve.

Comment: Correct, but there are actually two unknowns here. One is a function, and the other is a number, which are determined by the operator. What I meant is that I'm looking for equations that (for example) would enable me to find the eigenfunctions without knowledge of the eigenvalues..

Comment: I know this example is simple and very easy to solve. But it is just an example. If I'd like to solve the same problem with a much more complicated operator, using Mathematics software like Mathematica for example, I'm interested in equations that will enable me to find eigenfunctions regardless of eigenvalues..

Comment: The solution depends on the eigenvalue.  Whether it is an eigenfunction depends on boundary conditions, which you have not specified.